# How to use setBounds method for a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager

I'm making a window application with `Swing`. I am using the `setBounds()` method for the `JLabel` spacing but it's not working.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FullScreenJFrame extends JFrame
{
  public FullScreenJFrame( String title )
  {
      super(title);
      //JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

      setUndecorated(true);
      Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
      setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
      getContentPane()
      .add(new JLabel("    HIGHCOURT OF JUDICATURE AT ALLHAHABAD"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
      JLabel label = new JLabel("JJ");
      label.setBounds(20, 20, 150, 20);

      // label.setText(s);
      add(label);
  }

  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
      FullScreenJFrame frame = new FullScreenJFrame("");
      //JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
      //JLabel label = new JLabel("dd");
      //label.setBounds(370, 340, 150, 20);
      //frame1.add(label);
      frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by now working?

Comment: I guess there is a problem with the Layout. The first Label is inserted in the ContentPane, the second one not. You also mix BorderLayout and Null-Layout. Try creating a JPanel with your specific Layout (Border, Flow, null etc.), add the labels to the JPanel and then add the JPanel to the contentPane.

Comment: my mean is  label is not getting set on giving location

Answer (score -2, accepted):

### Are null layouts recommended? As other have suggested, the answer is

## NO

. 
See [**Laying out Components in a Container**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) to get some practice in with LayoutManagers

---

Will I still answer your question? Sure. Just so you know.

> "I am using the setBounds() method for the JLabel spacing but it's not working. Please, can any one tell me why it is not working?"

Yes, your bounds aren't working because the `JFrame` has a default `Borderlayout`. In order for `setBounds` to work, the layout needs to be `null`.

```
setLayout(null);
```

Also, keep in mind that when you *do* use a null layout, any components in which you *don't* `setBounds` for will not appear.

---

See [**Laying out Components in a Container**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) to get some practice in with LayoutManagers

Comment: I'm going to have to give this a -1 to warn others that this is *not* the way to go.  Admittedly you allude to the better approach in the last two paragraphs, but most newbies don't read that far.  It is more effective to constantly give the advice that it is the wrong way to go, and instead encourage the asker of the question to describe the layout they are trying to achieve, then show them how to do it with layouts, layout padding, borders and size hints in the columns and rows of components.  As it is, we can expect to see them again in a couple of days, asking us to fix the *next* problem.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I graciously accept the down-vote. Though at my defense, I was just simply trying to answer the direct question of the OP.

Comment: *"I was just simply trying to answer the direct question of the OP."*  My point is, sometimes it's best *not* to answer the question asked.  See this post on the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/155831).

Answer (score 3):

One advice, It seems you are going to show your application using all screen so try to avoid the use of absolute positions like setBoundMethod.

You should fit your application within a layout that uses other layouts within it. Check this link.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Answer (score 2):

**Don't** use `setBounds()` to resize a *component*. Use a [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) and you won't be worried about manually doing this.

Answer (score 2):

**Why?**

Why are going for absolute positioning, when [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) do it for you.

One more thing, If your JFrame does not contain any title so there is no need to add empty title as it is bad practice.

Replace

```
FullScreenJFrame frame = new FullScreenJFrame("");
```

By

```
FullScreenJFrame frame = new FullScreenJFrame();
```

And

```
public FullScreenJFrame( String title )
```

By

```
public FullScreenJFrame()
```

**No need to call**

```
super(title);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in order to set your layout as null right click on your form and click set layout then click null layout.